# How do i send a email on same thread using google-api-nodejs-client nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, gmail, gmail-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I have full response of a email send using node module google-api-nodejs-client, which is like 

`{
  "id": "1231212312", 
  "labelIds": ["UNREAD", "SENT", "INBOX"], 
  "threadId": "23123123"
}`

I need to send an email again to the email address but in the same thread not as a new email.

I checked the documentation but wasn't able to find relevant stuff.

Here is the link to its documentation: https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/apis/gmail/v1.js#L796

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order to make your message display in the same thread you need to make it RFC compliant which means you need to add the `In-Reply-To` and `References` header that includes the `Message-ID` (also a header) of the previous message.

Afterwards, you can then provide the `threadId` to the Gmail API which will then send it as the same thread. Gmail also requires that your "subject" be the same as the previous message.

References:

- https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send see "threadId" in the optional properties section

Comment: so instead of 'To' i need to add 'In-Reply-To' and References : messageId
i.e
```email_lines.push(`From:${user_account.email}`);
email_lines.push(`In-Reply-To:${contact_email}`);
email_lines.push(`References: '15a5236d11e3bb65'`);
email_lines.push('Content-type :text/html;charset=iso-8859-1');
email_lines.push('MIME-Version:1.0');```

and 

```gmail.users.messages.send({
    auth: oauth2Client,
    'userId': 'me',
    'threadId': '15a5236d11e3bb65',
    'resource': {
      'raw': base64EncodedEmail
    }
```
Right ? Some thing like this ?

Comment: You still need the To header, you just need to apply the other headers also. Referenes and In-Reply-To need to match the Message-ID header of the previous message.

Comment: An example of that Message-ID is `<CADeEaBjZA-6GNvy31Wj11kzrxU0uAsArNg346DOwMB2u_2gpnQ@mail.gmail.com>`

Comment: {"id": "15a5236d11e3bb65", "labelIds": ["UNREAD", "SENT", "INBOX"], "threadId": "15a5236d11e3bb65"}

so using this response -> Id@mail.gmail.com  is my message id right ?

Comment: No, you need to obtain the message after you send it using the id of your response. Then in the headers of the message you just sent you'll need find "message-id" and obtain that. This is the RFC 2822 header that you need to obtain.

Comment: Got it. Thank you. :)

Comment: I am getting permission issue while i am obtaining message id, can you let me know which permission is required ?